# Autodiscover POP/IMAP/SMTP settings from an email address

Tags: php, smtp, imap

We have an application that allows our users to connect their email address with SMTP. Our support team is having a nightmare helping clients find their details, so I have started building a way to select default settings from a list.

At the moment, I have listed 30+ providers, along with their most common settings. I have those on a json endpoint, and autofill the form based on the users selection.

This sort of works, but it relies on their provider being in that list.

Does anyone know of a way to automatically get the Host & Port, TLS etc automatically from a given email address?

I know you can do MX lookups, but that doesnt match the smtp host.

Kind of like this... https://www.emailsettings.email/ but it doesnt seem to work for custom domains.

Comment: Unless someone has made an API which does the exact same thing as your current autofill (i.e. look it up in a pre-made list), then no I don't believe you can do this. There's nothing in an email which address which gives you any clue about how the email provider's server is configured, you just have to know. If it was possible, then existing desktop mail clients (e.g. Thunderbird, MS Mail, Apple mail etc) would be able to do it already. But at most, they only ever auto-complete for the most popular providers - by looking it up in a pre-made list.

Comment: I would suggest the clients have at least some responsibility to understand who their email provider is, and be able to get the settings from them (most will publish them either publicly, or through a login to a web portal) - they'd have to do that if they were using a different mail client. But of course that doesn't mean you shouldn't try to help them.

Answer (score 0):

The information desired is contained within the DNS (MX/SRV) records as you stated. If that is not returned then it is not possible to auto-retrieve this information unless the provider has TXT records added with this information. In PHP the request would be done like this:

```
try 
{
    $hostname = 'domain.com';
    $authns = array();
    $addtl = array();
    $request = dns_get_record ($hostname, DNS_ANY, $authns, $addtl);
    var_dump($request);
}
catch (Exception $e)
{
    var_dump($e);
}
```

If the information is returned within TXT records there must be a sanity check to ensure it is properly entered as it is a TXT record and there is no restriction.